# NotAuthorizedException when send verification code using Cognito with React

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I've create an React application using AWS Amplify, and I getting and error with recover password feature.

When I put e-mail and call forgot password function, I'm receiving status code 400 with message: NotAuthorizedException: Contact administrator to reset password.

I checked my App Role, and I have "cognito-idp:AdminResetUserPassword" permission.

That's my code:

```
const sendCode = (event,email) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const cognitoUser = new CognitoUser({
        Username: email.toLowerCase(),
        Pool: UserPool
    });

    // call forgotPassword on cognitoUser
    cognitoUser.forgotPassword({
        onSuccess: function(result) {
            alert(`Verification code sent to: ${email}!`)
        },
        onFailure: function(err) {
            alert(`Error while send verification code to: ${email} - ${err}`);
        },
    });
}
```

How can I get that permission?

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem, and the solution is simple. The feature of recover accounts was disable, I just enable it and it works.